# Centos8 Thunderbird no outgoing connection

Tags: centos, thunderbird

i face the following problem.

OS: CentOS 8.1.1911
Mail Client: thunderbird-68.7.0-1.el8_1.x86_64
Mail Provider: gmx.net

If i try to sent an mail the thunderbird doesn't connect to the network interface. Telnet does.

```
telnet mail.gmx.net 465
Trying 212.227.17.190...
Connected to mail.gmx.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
^CConnection closed by foreign host.
```

So, firewall is open on my computer and in the router.

With wireshark i can see the connection from telnet goes over my internet connection. But thunderbird doesn't show up there.

With strace i face a problem, in a loop:

```
recvmsg(4, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar)
recvmsg(4, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=34, events=POLLIN}], 4, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvmsg(4, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar)
recvmsg(4, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=34, events=POLLIN}], 4, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvmsg(4, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar)
recvmsg(4, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=34, events=POLLIN}], 4, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvmsg(4, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar)
recvmsg(4, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=34, events=POLLIN}], 4, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvmsg(4, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar)
recvmsg(4, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=34, events=POLLIN}], 4, -1^C) = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (Interrupted by signal)
strace: Process 103995 detached
```

How to proceed?
Where can i check further why thunderbird doesn't connect to my internet connection?
Any advise is welcome.
BR Dirk

Comment: did u checked if all required input/outputs ports are open?

Comment: This is not my router, it is in e cafe.
But with my telnet check, i thought that i have checked the port 465 outgoing, and incoming i should be a random port. In my understanding.
A test now in an other enviroment, leads me to the point that thunderbird works without any changes.
Is it possible to forward port 465 local to port 443 and then after the router back to 465?
Sorry, if this is a silly question.

Comment: I have no idea with port forwarding. you should try some different mail client ,it may help you to isolate issue.